# How to prevent an application from being executed?

Tags: c++, c, windows, winapi

I need to prevent an application from being started on a windows machine. The most obvious way (having an infinite loop and using EnumProcesses/OpenProcess/TerminateProcess) implies that the target application/process has already been started and also that it ran for a certain period of time.

Renaming/editing/patching/deleting the target application sadly isn't an option.

Comment: Do you want your program not to be invoked again, if the first one is running?

Comment: So you're trying to prevent multiple instances of an application that you don't actually "own" (as in you can't modify at the source to self-terminate on multi-instance detection at startup)?

Comment: What are you really trying to do?

Comment: I either go with hooking CreateProcess (edit: or rather NtCreateSection) itself or with AppLocker (thanks Nikos C.) now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are running Windows 7 or newer (or anything based on it), then you can use the AppLocker feature:

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd723686(v=ws.10).aspx

Answer (score 1):

Without replacing the code inside the unwanted executable? I don't think you can. Unless you  break into the Windows kernel at least. See if the unwanted program has a schedule or a trigger that causes it to run. Maybe you can get rid of them. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [CBT hook](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644977%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to inject hook dll into applications. 
Then desired process can be terminated from inside hook procedure.
This applies to Windows 2000 and above.